# Firebase Database for Unity HTML5

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have imported Firebase database package which works perfectly fine on Android and iOS but the same is not working on HTML5. Does Firebase Database support HTML5 in unity.
Below is the error which I am constantly receiving:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Database' does not exist in the namespace `Firebase'. 
              Are you missing an assembly reference?
```